# ASP.NET MVC Class level custom data-annotation and ModelState keys

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have custom class level validation attribute, inheriting from ValidationAttribute, on my model.

How come it doesn't register a key in the ModelState when its IsValid is false? I can see the the error message in the ModelState.Values collection, but the ModelState.Keys collection only shows an empty string "". Can I provide a key for it - presumably this is because its not assigned to a property?

I wanna be able to use ModelState.Remove in my controller to remove this error upon a certain condition, but I have no Key!

Any ideas?

Comment: I have same problem, I needed to check multiple values so I mad a class level custom attribute but I get nothing back to the view showing that I have an error. I am getting the impression that using data annotations for model validation is lack luster at best.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266632/unable-to-set-membernames-from-custom-validation-attribute-in-mvc2 has same problem and a solution also hope tat helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking ModelError.Exception in IModelBinder.OnModelUpdated.