# What determines the key in the ModelStateDictionary for Items of Collection Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, modelstate, addmodelerror, modelstatedictionary

**If this is my view model:**

```
 public class ViewModel{
      public string SimpleProperty{get;set;}
      public SubViewModel ComplexProperty{ get;set;}
      public SubViewModel[] ComplexPropertyArray{ get; set; }
 }

 public class SubViewModel{
      public string NestedSimpleProperty{get;set;}
 }
```

**Then what would be the default error message keys assigned to a `ModelStateDictionary` for:**

1. <s>ViewModel.SimpleProperty</s> *(see update below)*
2. <s>ViewModel.ComplexProperty</s> *(see update below)*
3. <s>ViewModel.ComplexProperty.NestedSimpleProperty</s> *(see update below)*
4. <s>ViewModel.ComplexPropertyArray</s> *(see update below)*
5. **ViewModel.ComplexPropertyArray[0]**
6. **ViewModel.ComplexPropertyArray[0].NestedSimpleProperty**

**Update**  I found this in reflector:

```
protected internal static string CreateSubPropertyName(string prefix, string propertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
    {
        return propertyName;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
    {
        return prefix;
    }
    return (prefix + "." + propertyName);
 }
```

So, I think that covers everything except for **#5 and #6**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `NestedSimpleProperty` required:

```
public class SubViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string NestedSimpleProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

and then you have a form in which you have multiple textboxes for this property corresponding to each item in the `ComplexPropertyArray` collection then the key that will be used for error messages will be `ComplexPropertyArray[i].NestedSimpleProperty` where `i` represents the index of the element in the array which contains an empty value.

Comment: Will I have any error associated with `ViewModel.ComplexPropertyArray[0]`, or only with its property?

Comment: @smartcaveman, no, in this case you will only have an error associated to `ComplexPropertyArray[0].NestedSimpleProperty`. You could inspect the ModelState property in the POST action of your controller in which you will find the `ModelState["ComplexPropertyArray[0].NestedSimpleProperty"].Errors;` value.

Comment: @Darin, ok, last question - Can I have an error associated with the model root (as in a validation attribute that decorates `ViewModel`)?  If so, what would its key be?

Comment: @smartcaveman, usually when you write a custom validator attribute and decorate your view model class with it there is no corresponding key in the ModelState => it will be an empty string. That's a great PITA when working with Data Annotations as you can only display the error message in the view using a validation summary.

Comment: @smartcaveman, personally I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead of Data Annotations to perform my validation logic and I don't have such problems. I prefer imperative validation rather than declarative as it is much more powerful and allows me to handle complex validation scenarios.

Comment: @Darin, thanks for that - it looks promising.  Does it follow the same convention as the DataAnnotations for ModelStateDictionary keys?

Comment: @Darin, does it follow the same ModelStateDictionary key conventions as DataAnnotations?

Comment: @smartcaveman, yes, it is based on the Property names for which you define validators.

Comment: Okay, so with FluentValidation.NET what is the key for a top level model, such as `ViewModel` in this example?

Comment: @smartcaveman, in FluentValidation.NET when you define a rule you always associate it to some property, so there is no such thing as top level view model key.

Comment: So, you can't have a rule about the class as a whole.  Is there support for validations that require multiple property values such as a city being in a state or two password fields having the same value?  If so, what would the key be for such an error?  I'm reading the documentation and I really like the way the API looks - sorry to ask so many questions.

Comment: @smartcaveman, let's take the example of passwords that match. The rule could look like this: `RuleFor(x => x.Password).Equal(x => x.PasswordConfirmation);` in which case the key error message will be associated to the property you are defining the rule for i.e. : `Password`.

Comment: Okay, awesome, thanks a million bro - I'm definitely going to use this framework

Comment: @smartcaveman When creating class level attribute by sub classing from ValidationAttribute , if the validation fails there is no corresponding key in the ModelState => it will be an empty string but a work around is provided in link provided below which will set the key name & help U to display the error message in ur View by using just the html.ValidationMessage("urpropertyname"). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266632/unable-to-set-membernames-from-custom-validation-attribute-in-mvc2